# Connecting to free AWS RDS instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm inexperienced with AWS but in the past have successfully started RDS instances, but that was some time ago (before default security was made more complicated). Now I'm trying a free tier MySQL db. I have made multiple attempts, but even with the most basic (all defaults), I'm unable to connect at all using any tools. I also can't ping the instance.

The default VPC had two routing table entries, as it is supposed to (one for the subnet and one for all other traffic, to go to the internet gateway), and my RDS instance is in this VPC. The default security group allows all ports inbound.

I have included a reference to the SSL CA pem file in the connection request, that was downloaded from Amazon.

Is there anything else I need to do? What am I missing?

If one of you could tell me how to create just the simplest default free DB with no security (this is just for a POC), I will be eternally in your debt.

Comment: Why are you using a .pem file? Ensure the security group has MySQL port open. Also check the DB is publicly routable.

Comment: @MattAuerbach the pem file is the ssl ca file for validating the SSL cert the RDS instance presents to you when you try to negotiate SSL with it.

Comment: FWIW: RDS instances are not pingable, regardless of security group settings. That's how it's designed, so don't bother testing that.  Are you trying to connect from an EC2 instance inside the VPC, or from outside, across the Internet?

Comment: Hi @Michael-sqlbot, I'm connecting from a PC at home, across the internet. Thank you for the tip about pinging it, I should have known better! Just starting a fresh, default no-option RDS instance can't be connected to over the internet without further work?

Comment: You have to configure it to have a public IP address, or have another way to access the VPC (like a tunnel/VPN).  If the address is in the ranges 10.x.x.x or 172.16.x.x-172.31.x.x or 192.168.x.x that's private, and not Internet-accessible.  If the IP is public you have to allow access from your IP in the security group.

Comment: Did you try following the sample in the documentation? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.CreatingConnecting.MySQL.html